# Rails: jQuery-UI vs bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been using Twitter Bootstrap. Now I need some features of jQuery UI and there is a handy gem jquery-ui-rails: https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails.

How can I make sure Bootstrap always has priority over JS functions & CSS also defined in jQuery UI, for example ".tooltip()"?

If I have to download and manually add jquery-ui files, I can do this, but if there is a clean way to make Bootstrap take priority, it would be preferable.

Comment: Why do you want to achieve priority ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add bootstrap after jQuery in your manifest files or when included directly in the layout. For example:

*application.css*

```
/*
*= require jquery-ui
*= require bootstrap
*/
```

*layout*

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery-ui', 'bootstrap'
```

PS: This is true at least for CSS, not sure for JS.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably a bit late, but it may be worth checking out [jQuery UI Bootstrap](http://addyosmani.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/). You probably want to use the [masterbs3 branch](http://github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap/tree/masterbs3) if using Bootstrap 3, though it's apparently still in alpha.